# ASP.NET Webapp hosting options other than IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, hosting

what are the options available to host ASP.NET 4.0 WebApp/website other than IIS?
In IIS we are facing issues like upload up to 4 GB, serve multiple requests etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the specific features you are using you can use [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/) running inside e.g apache. I am using this combination very successfully in some deployments - as soon as it runs it is very stable.

But you need to verify that everything from the .NET framework your application is using is already implemented in Mono and the setup is much more complicated IMO. Especially if you are using one of the common server OS like CentOS/RHEL or Ubunutu, as you very likely need to compile the latest mono version on your system as there are no official pre-compiled packages.

You also mentioned you have problems serving multiple requests - what is the problem there, as this should be no problem with IIS?